# javascript facebook publish on the wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

there are many answer on this issue, but I can't find the right solution!
I have javascript that calls the login, but with no premission to post to the wall

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $this->getAppID; ?>',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

In the php code it is very simpel added in the array like:

```
 $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope' => 'publish_stream'                                         ));
```

but how can I add it to the javascript button this url to ask permission to post to the wall of the user

Answer (score 1):

You ask for permissions using the scope parameter:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   alert(response);
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

[Read more](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/):

**EDIT:**

Javascript:

```
function login() {
FB.login(function(response) {
   alert(response);
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
}
```

HTML:
`<div onclick="login();return false;">click here to login</div>`

Comment: ok if I place it then it goes as popup on the load and I want to go on the click on the button <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>

Comment: You can place it inside a function and call it on a click event.

Comment: now I have one popup with premissions and under with basic login, I placed on click event on <fb:button onclick="login()"> but now I get twee where can I delete the one that I dont want

Comment: you need to cancel the <fb:button>